# how i can stretch my spinner width till 2nd item on layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my relative layout, I have a spinner and an imagebutton. I placed my image button in the right corner through the code below:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Now, I want my spinner to stretch its width to the left of my image button. I can acheive this by using fixed width of my spinner, but I want it dynamically so it can adjust to any screen size.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/coa_searchAccount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube_searched_for_black_18dp"
    />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/coa_parentid"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/coa_searchAccount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Spinner>
```

[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRPqP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Align your `ImageView` to the right and then align the `Spinner` to the left of the `ImageView`

Use something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/your_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/your_dimen"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@color/your_drawable" />

</RelativeLayout>
```